# To add space before AM/PM

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

I have a string like `"06:35PM"`. I want to add a space before AM/PM, resulting in `"06:35 PM"`.

```
var timeValue = "06:35PM";
var hours = Number(timeValue.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
var minutes = Number(timeValue.match(/:(\d+)/)[1]);
var AMPM = timeValue.match(/\s(.*)$/)[1];
travelInfo.PreCruise[field] = hours + ":" + minutes + " " + AMPM;
```

But at the 4th line, I get this error: `Cannot read property '1' of null`.

How can I write a regular expression to do this?

Comment: Note that by parsing the numbers and then appending them, you'll lose any leading `0`s.

Answer (score 2):

How about?:

```
str.replace("A", " A").replace("P", " P");
```

Comment: How about it? What does it do differently? Why do you think it should be done that way? Useful answers *explain*.

Comment: Hi T.J.Crowder Sir, I understood the requirement as: He simply wants to put a space between last digit and "A" or "P". If his requirement is strict, then I find my solution will work as it simply replaces the "A" and "P" with additional space in front.

Answer (score 2):

Just do a single replace without parsing the numbers:

```
timeValue = timeValue.replace(/[AP]/, " $&");
```

```js
var timeValue = "06:35PM";
timeValue = timeValue.replace(/[AP]/, " $&");
console.log(timeValue);
```

The regex `[AP]` matches an `A` or a `P`. The replacement string has the space you want, and `$&` which means "insert whatever matched here," meaning that `$&` will take the value `A` if it was an `A` that matched, or `P` if it was a `P` that matched.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `s` with `S`as `s` Find a whitespace character which you don't have,

```
var AMPM = timeValue.match(/\S(.*)$/)[1];
```

Comment: Why? What does it do? Why do you need to do that? Useful answers *explain*.

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe something as simple as adding space before last two alphabets

**Demo**

```js
var timeValue = "06:35PM";
console.log( timeValue.split(/(?=[A-Z]{2})/).join(" ") );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
var timeValue = "06:35PM";
// get the last two characters
var last2 = timeValue.slice(-2);
// Create a substring removing the last two characters
var x = timeValue.substr(0, timeValue.length-2)
// concat them adding a space in between
var t = x+' '+last2
console.log(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Regular expression.

```
/\S(.*)$/
```

Hope it helps.